Post migration issues with ranking
We recently migrated our website to WordPress, changing our URL structure from 'www.example.com/blog-post' to 'www.example.com/blog-post/' by adding trailing slashes. Following this, we implemented 301 redirects from the non-trailing slash URLs to the new trailing slash URLs.
Since the migration, Google has deindexed all of our old URLs and reindexed the new ones. However, the search engine ranking positions (SERPs) for our posts have dropped from positions 1-8 to positions 20-35, despite the content and incoming, internal links remaining the same.
Is this drop in SERP ranking likely to be temporary following the URL structure change?
Are there any additional steps we should take to help recover our previous rankings?
How long does it typically take for rankings to stabilize after such a change?
Things to know:

We did technical audits using SEM and Screaming Frog. Everything is in order.
We checked all urls to make sure they work fine.
Google has fully reindexed all our pages.
This migration happened on March 10th.
I don't understand how ...com/example-post used to be ranked position 3, then completely deindexed and reindexed with the trailing slash but now as position 25.

Thank you so much for your help.

First of all, such changes must not be made on a live website. You could have retained the urls without trailing slashes in Wordpress.
Just needed to remove the trailing slash in permalink settings. After 301 redirections are applied, Google will index the new ones but the rankings may decline and take some weeks or 1-2 months to come back to normal.

If your rankings don't return within a couple of weeks I can only think of one situation that could cause issues here and that's that your canonical URLs are still set to the non-trailing slash versions.

Double check canonical URLs
Ensure that all internal links point to a non-trailing slash version
Ensure that your sitemaps all serve the new trailing-slash version

For future reference, or for anyone who finds this page through search engines, I will mention that it would have been entirely possible to continue with a non-slash style on WordPress.
First, you'd edit your configuration files:
Apache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>


Nginx
location / {
    # Handle trailing slash removal
    rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;

    # Other existing directives like try_files, etc.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

Then update your permalink structure to custom without the slash eg. /foo/%postname%
